# log4net not saving in Database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem with log4net. In localhost works fine and save in the database (Production1), then in QA not save the log in the same database (Production1)

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Web.config", Watch = true)]
```

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <!-- Log4Net -->
  <log4net>

    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="wsaopc.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1024KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="debug" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
      <immediateFlush value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="sql" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionStringName value="CSLog4Net" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO aopc_sce_ws_log (wslog_fecha, wslog_tarea, wslog_nivel,wslog_logger, wslog_mensaje, wslog_excepcion) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <logger name="WS">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="sql" />
      <appender-ref ref="debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="EF">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderEF" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="BD">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="sql" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>     

</configuration>
```

I review in QA and have the same web.config.

Comment: How can we answer if you are just telling us that everything is exactly the same? Something must be different or it would work, so work out what is different

Comment: Is the DB server reachable from the QA environment? Could you log the SQL statements using sql profiler and see if they are received?